# Is it possible for a UUIDV4 to contain only letters or only numbers and the corresponding dashes?

Tags: javascript, uuid, sqldatatypes

//only letters example:

const onlyLtrs= "gheccasf-dffg-hjkl-apoi-auytarfewbfq";

//only numbers example:

const onlyNums = "67890987-6543-2123-4567-890987654321";

I'm trying to test if a string is a uuid using regexp. I know how to do it. But if it is possible a uuid to only contain letters then I should change some regex's.

Comment: These are [hexadecimal digits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier#Format) so only `a-f` letters

Comment: "*I know how to do it.*" - can you show the regex you're using, please?

Comment: What does this have to do with JavaScript or SQL?

Comment: [An UUID is a 128 bit label](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier) (16 bytes) encoded using the base 16 (hexadecimal). Assuming that an UUID contains only digits or only letters is a mistake. Modifying an UUID to contain only digits or only letters is a bigger mistake because there are many chances to generate duplicate values. If you don't want to write a regex to match an UUID, you can use an [existing Npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=uuid) for that. There probably are several dozens of them on the Npm repository.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible for a UUIDV4 to contain only letters?

No. In v4 specifically, [the 15th digit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier#Format) is a `4`.

> … or only numbers and the corresponding dashes?

Yes, that's possible. (Though rather unlikely, around 0.08% of randomly generated UUIDs)

> only letters example:
>
> ```
> const onlyLtrs= "gheccasf-dffg-hjkl-apoi-auytarfewbfq";
> ```

That's not a valid UUID, which is represented using [hexadecimal digits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal).